# Diferencia entre declaracion de structs

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos

## 1er código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct{
   int edad;
   char *ptr;

}hola;

int main(){

    hola.edad=2;

    printf("%d\n",hola.edad);
    hola.ptr=malloc(5);
    strcpy(hola.ptr,"Hola");

    printf("%s",hola.ptr);
    free(hola.ptr);


    return 0;
}
```

## 2º codigo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct hola{
   int edad;
   char *ptr;

}holas;

int main(){

    holas.edad=2;

    printf("%d\n",holas.edad);
    holas.ptr=malloc(5);
    strcpy(holas.ptr,"Hola");

    printf("%s",holas.ptr);
    free(holas.ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

¿Qué diferencia habría de declarar una `struct` como en el primer ejemplo,

```
struct{
   int edad;
   char *ptr;

}hola;
```

... o declararla así como en el segundo ejemplo?

```
struct hola{
   int edad;
   char *ptr;

}holas;
```

¿La segunda es mas clara al ponerle un nombre a la `struct`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Caso 1

```
struct{
   int edad;
   char *ptr;

}hola;
```

Aquí estás declarando una variable llamada `hola` que está basada en una estructura anónima. Nota que no vas a poder crear más variables basadas en esta estructura ya que la misma no tiene nombre.

## Caso 2

```
struct hola{
   int edad;
   char *ptr;

}holas;
```

Aquí, en cambio, creas una estructura de nombre `hola` y, seguidamente, declaras una variable llamada `holas` basada en dicha estructura. Al tener, en este caso, un nombre la estructura, podrás crear nuevas variables basadas en esta estructura cuando lo necesites:

```
struct hola otraVariable;
```

¿Qué opción es mejor? Depende de tus necesidades. En cualquier caso no es buena idea andar declarando variables globales con alegría así que tus ejemplos no siguen precisamente buenas prácticas.

Por otro lado, declarar la variable a la vez que la estructura puede dar lugar a código menos legible. Mi experiencia es que suele ser recomendable separar la declaración de la estructura de la declaración de variables:

```
struct hola
{
  /* ... */
};

struct hola unaVariable;
```

Para que la declaración de variables basadas en estructuras sea menos aparatosa podemos recurrir al uso de `typedef`. Como podrás ver en los dos ejemplos siguientes, el simple hecho de usar `typedef` modifica el comportamiento del programa ya que no se van a poder declarar estructuras y variables a la vez, así que este es otro punto a favor para evitar confusiones.

## Caso 1 (con typedef)

```
typedef struct{
   int edad;
   char *ptr;
}hola;
```

En este primer caso estamos creando una estructura anónima y, seguidamente, le asignamos un alias a dicha estructura (Nota que aquí ya no se declaran variables). Pese a ser una estructura anónima, el hecho de tener un alias nos va a permitir declarar variables basadas en esta estructura en cualquier parte del código:

```
hola unaVariable;
```

## Caso 2 (con typedef)

El siguiente ejemplo, en cambio:

```
typedef struct holas{
   int edad;
   char *ptr;
}hola;
```

Declara una estructura con nombre `holas` y, seguidamente, le asigna un alias llamado `hola`. En este caso tendremos dos vías diferentes para declarar variables:

```
struct holas unaVariable;
hola otraVariable;
```

Comment: @Maur no pasa nada. Para eso están los comentarios :). Voy a borrar mis comentarios anteriores ya que han perdido toda su utilidad. Condiera borrar los tuyos también para dejar esto lo más limpio posible

Answer (score 3):

La diferencia entre ambas definiciones de `structs` es el identificador que incluyes después de la palabra reservada `struct`. Incluir el identificador en la declaración de un `struct` permite que se pueda instanciar una variable de esa estructura, mientas que, si no lo incluyes, únicamente podrás instanciar variables de ese mismo `struct` únicamente en la definición del `struct`.

Los `structs` que carecen de identificadores son anónimos, debido a que no tienen un nombre que los identifique.

> **En esta [página](http://c.conclase.net/curso/index.php?cap=011#inicio) del sitio C Con Clase  definen así la sintaxis de una estructura y una estructura anónima:**
>
> ```
> struct [<identificador>] { 
>     [<tipo> <nombre_objeto>[,<nombre_objeto>,...]];
> } [<objeto_estructura>[,<objeto_estructura>,...];
> ```
>
> El  identificador de la estructura es un nombre opcional para
>   referirse a la estructura.
>
> **En esta otra [página](http://c.conclase.net/curso/index.php?cap=011b#STR_Anonimas) nos aclara que son las estructuras anónimas:**
>
> Hay situaciones donde se pueden omitir ambos identificadores.
>
> Una estructura anónima es la que carece de identificador de tipo de
>   estructura y de declaración de objetos del tipo de estructura.
>
> Por ejemplo, veamos esta declaración:
>
> ```
> struct stAnonima { 
>     struct { 
>         int x; 
>         int y; 
>     }; 
>     int z;
> };
> ```

Aquí te dejo las páginas para que sigas leyendo:

[Objetos III: Estructuras](http://c.conclase.net/curso/index.php?cap=011#inicio)

[Objetos III: Estructuras anónimas](http://c.conclase.net/curso/index.php?cap=011b#STR_Anonimas)

Comment: ¿Por qué pones los enlaces dos veces? Es solo curiosidad

Comment: Porque me parece que es adecuado.

Answer (score 1):

En el primer caso estás creando un struct "anónimo" y dándole un nombre al final de la declaración del mismo. En el segundo creas un struct con nombre, pero después le vuelves a poner un nombre al final de la declaración, creando así una variable llamada 'holas', por lo que queda muy redundante en mi opinión. La mejor manera de hacerlo sería la siguiente:

```
 struct hola { 
  int edad; char *ptr; 
 };

struct hola c = { .edad= "x", .ptr="y" };
```

Actualización:

A efectos prácticos

```
struct hola { 
  int edad; char *ptr; 
 }c;

struct hola c = ...
```

Sería lo mismo que crear un elemento tipo 'hola', dicho lo cuál lo más óptimo es crear un tipo de dato por defecto inalterable, y en el momento de instanciarlo darle un nombre y darle los valores correspondientes.

Comment: perdona se me envió ante de tiempo, espero que te sea útil, un saludo.

Comment: Nono, perdona tu, que me he liado. No termino de estar de acuerdo: das un nombre al final de la declaración ... ¿ a que ? Y eso del alias ... ¿ eso que pones en el ejemplo es un *alias* ? O no te estás explicando bien, o yo no te estoy entendiendo.

Comment: Entonces mejor hacer struct hola y luego darle un alias

Comment: Mejor hacer un struct como tal con un nombre. En la siguiente línea lo que hago es como se declararía un elemento tipo 'hola' al que le puedes poner el nombre que quieras, en este caso le he puesto 'c'. Respecto a lo del alías me refería a que es redundante poner "dos nombres" que es en realidad lo que está pasando. Estás creando un tipo de dato struct llamado 'hola' y estás llamandolo 'holas' para referirte a 'hola'. Es un poco lioso.

Comment: Entonces, según tú, ` struct hola { int edad; } c;` en realidad está creando **2** nombres para una misma `struct` ?? Entonces, luego podría hacer `struct c mystruct;` ??

Comment: Pero un alias no seria con typedef?

Comment: Al hacer struct hola esto es como hacer int y luego al hacer struct hola holas es como hacer int holas si no me quivoco

Comment: struct hola { 
  int edad; char *ptr; 
 }holas; holas es una variable de tipo struct no?

Comment: struct hola { int edad; char *ptr; } c; == struct hola c ...

Comment: @Trauma será la respuesta ¿no?

Comment: @eferion es lo que estaba intentando decir gracias

Comment: @eferion vale muchas gracias y perdón por las molestias ocasionadas a todos, por la confusión.

Comment: @eferion vale gracias, creo que así estaría mejor.